# Multiple Authors, Multiple Affiliations without authblk

Tags: author-number, authblk

I am trying to make a latex template for reuse by me and other people in my lab.
The template reference is a word doc. I have gotten most of the way using the asme2e class, but I am having trouble with the author blocks.

This is the target:
[image]

I've tried authblk to do this, but authblk will not load for me.
I get an error:

```
authblk.sty:113: Undefined control sequence. [\xdef\AB@author{\noexpand\AB@blk@and\@author]
```

So, I am trying to do this without authblk, but have the solution be as simple as possible so others (and myself a year from now) can use it. Others may have more than or less than 3 authors.

For example, I don't want to abuse title like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166164/multiple-authors-with-multiple-affiliations).

Here is some code that include my preamble.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}
\bibliographystyle{asmems4}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphics,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,indentfirst,subfig,float}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\papernum{XXXXX-XXXXX}

\title{Your Title Here}
\conffullname{Proceeding of the ASME Super Awesome Conference}

\confdate{xx-xx}
\confmonth{XXXX}
\confyear{XXX}
\confcity{city, state}
\confcountry{country}

%%%
 %AUTHOR STUFF WOULD GO HERE....
%%%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Introduction}
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like that could help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214425/828

Comment: Those are added as footnotes.

Comment: I know that the affiliations are added as footnotes, but maybe you could use another pointer with that trick.