# Authors and affiliations

Tags: affiliation

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{A Very Clever Paper Title}

\author[add1]{Author1}
\ead{email1@domain.ca}
\author[add2, add3]{Author2}
\ead{email2@domain.ca}
\author[add2, add3]{Author3}
\ead{email3@domain.ca}


\address[add1]{Department of Redundancy Department}
\address[add2]{Centre for Study of Things}
\address[add3]{Department of Interests}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

In the above case, how can I merge affiliations for Author2 and Author3 if they are equal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authors with multiple affiliations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/authors-with-multiple-affiliations)

Comment: @zyy This is about a different documentclass.

Answer (score 24):

- Spaces after the comma in the optional argument of `\author` are not supported by class `elsarticle`. ☹
- Also the class does not generate a rerun warning, the letters for the affiliations are not yet known in the first LaTeX run.

### A. Example without merging

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{A Very Clever Paper Title}

\author[add1]{Author1}
\ead{email1@domain.ca}
\author[add2,add3]{Author2}
\ead{email2@domain.ca}
\author[add2,add3]{Author3}
\ead{email3@domain.ca}

\address[add1]{Department of Redundancy Department}
\address[add2]{Centre for Study of Things}
\address[add3]{Department of Interests}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result A]

### B. Two affiliations in one line

```
\author[add1]{Author1}
\ead{email1@domain.ca}
\author[add2]{Author2}
\ead{email2@domain.ca}
\author[add2]{Author3}
\ead{email3@domain.ca}

\address[add1]{Department of Redundancy Department}
\address[add2]{Centre for Study of Things; Department of Interests}
```

> [image: Result B]

- Disadvantage: The second affiliation in the line gets lost visually.
  It is not clear, that the both authors have two affiliations.

### C. Affiliations in two lines

```
\author[add1]{Author1}
\ead{email1@domain.ca}
\author[add2]{Author2}
\ead{email2@domain.ca}
\author[add2]{Author3}
\ead{email3@domain.ca}

\address[add1]{Department of Redundancy Department}
\address[add2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Centre for Study of Things\\
     Department of Interests 
  \end{tabular}% 
}
```

> [image: Result C]

- Disadvantage: IMHO better than the previous variant, but it is not clear at the first glance that there are two affiliations under "b" and that both authors have two affiliations.

**Summary:** I prefer the first version A, [clear and simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Thanks @Heiko Oberdiek for very helpful answer. I do a have a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303678/4821). Would highly appreciate if you have a look on this and provide any answer. Thanks