# Multiple Affiliations for First Author

Tags: titles

The `siamart0516` template is unable to specify multiple affiliations for the first author. The journal suggests that one should use `\thanks` and `\footnotemark` to specify affiliations and then duplicates, if necessary.

- `\thanks` generates an affiliation. There cannot seem to be more than one per author.
- `\thanks` cannot be followed by a `\footnotemark`.

Thus, the first author can be affiliated with atmost one entity. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this? Modifying the underlying template will only annoy the copy editors and would prefer a solution which doesn't utilize it.

A simple example where this situation is as follows

```
\documentclass{siamart0516}

\author{
AB_Guy \thanks{A}
\and
AB_Girl \footnotemark[1] \footnotemark[2]
\and
A_Guy \thanks{B}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I'm aiming for A and B `\thanks` to appear for both `AB_Guy` and `AB_Girl`. But no combination of options is able to give me two affiliations for `AB_Guy`.

Comment: see if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/authors-with-multiple-affiliations

Comment: Please post an actual (but minimal!) example if the above link does not help. It is usually quite tedious to try to create a problem or error we do not have based off a verbal description.

Comment: The above link modifies the `author` command in the class, which is not recommended for journals and will not annoy copy writers. I would be glad to try out other suggestions.