# Section with different font sizes AND author with more than one affiliation

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, affiliation

I'm new to LaTeX and I have two doubts concerning this paper template that was provided by the congress: [Paper Template - Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qfycqqrwbwtg).

**1 Doubt (not solved)**: They say that the first letter of the headings must be 12pt and the other 8pt. When I generate the PDF file and open it using my PDF reader, the first letter size is ok, but the others are something around 9, 9.5, or 10pt. How can I solve this?

The image below shows what I want (blue, with the first letter 12pt and others 8pt) and what I got after compiling (black, with the first letter 12pt and others 10pt).

The .cls file contains this codes about `\section`:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\center \large \textsc}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.\hspace{-3mm}}
```

[image]

**2 Doubt (solved)**: I've tried (without success) to add two affiliations to the same author.
To solve it I've added the following code to the .cls file, according to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/authors-with-multiple-affiliations).

```
\renewcommand{\author}[3][]{
      \stepcounter{ifmbe@authors}
      \expandafter\def\csname ifmbe@author\alph{ifmbe@authors}\endcsname
      {#2$^{\expandafter\the\csname ifmbe@affiliationcounter#3\endcsname
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else,#1\fi}$}
}
```

So, I've done the following in my `main.tex` providing the figure below.

```
\documentclass[nouppercase]{ifmbe}

\title{Paper Title - XXX YYY Congress - 2022}

\affiliation{Department of Electrical Engineering, University of Somewhere, City, Country}{FIRSTAFF}
\affiliation{Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of Somewhere, City, Country}{SECONDAFF}

\author{First Author}{FIRSTAFF}
% changed from \author{Second Author}{SECONDAFF} to:
\author[2]{Second Author}{FIRSTAFF}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This paper presents instructions for preparing papers. The template is intended to guide the authors in  preparing the electronic version of their paper. Only papers prepared according to these instructions will be published in both, the paper and online version. In this abstract section you should provide an abstract of your paper, not longer than 300 words.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile which shows what you have tried and what the problem is. The `.cls` file should produce the output you are after, so best not to change it.

Comment: @PeterWilson thanks. I've added some code example above, but the main.tex in https://www.overleaf.com/read/qfycqqrwbwtg by itself is an MWE. I'd like the second author to be associated to both affiliations, preferably using their way of adding affiliations.

Comment: @PeterWilson I've solved the affiliations problem as above. But the section letters (second to last) keep around 10pt, and the required is 8pt.

Comment: Perhaps someone else will help you with that.